# Checking number of adjacent tiles belonging to a player and calculating the score

Tags: java

So, I am trying to work out how many adjacent tiles there are for each player and calculate a total score. Calculating the score works by counting how many adjacent tiles (adjacent means sharing an edge not diagonally) there are per territory, multiplying that number by itself and adding the values of all the territories together.

So far I have the code below, which splits all the spaces out per player and can print whether or not a space is occupied by the player but I am stuck on calculating how many tiles are adjacent to each other.

```
    public void calculate(PowerToken[][] allTokens){
            boolean[][] occupiedRed = new boolean[9][9];
            boolean[][] occupiedWhite = new boolean[9][9];
    
            boolean[][] countedRed = new boolean[9][9];
            boolean[][] countedWhite = new boolean[9][9];
    
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
                    if (allTokens[i][j].isOnBoard()) {
                        if (allTokens[i][j].getPlayerColor() == Color.RED){
                            occupiedRed[i][j] = true;
                        } else {
                            occupiedWhite[i][j] = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
        }



        // Test printing
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
                System.out.print(occupiedWhite[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
                System.out.print(occupiedRed[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

**Power Token Class**

```
public class PowerToken {
    private int positionX;
    private int positionY;

    private boolean onBoard;

    private Color playerColor;

    public PowerToken(int positionX, int positionY) {
        setPositionX(positionX);
        setPositionY(positionY);
    }

    public PowerToken(int positionX, int positionY, boolean onBoard, Color playerColor) {
        setPositionX(positionX);
        setPositionY(positionY);
        setOnBoard(onBoard);
        setPlayerColor(playerColor);
    }

    public int getPositionX() {
        return positionX;
    }

    public void setPositionX(int positionX) {
        this.positionX = positionX;
    }

    public int getPositionY() {
        return positionY;
    }

    public void setPositionY(int positionY) {
        this.positionY = positionY;
    }

    public boolean isOnBoard() {
        return onBoard;
    }

    public void setOnBoard(boolean onBoard) {
        this.onBoard = onBoard;
    }

    public Color getPlayerColor() {
        return playerColor;
    }

    public void setPlayerColor(Color playerColor) {
        this.playerColor = playerColor;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PowerToken{" +
                "positionX=" + positionX +
                ", positionY=" + positionY +
                ", onBoard=" + onBoard +
                ", playerColor=" + playerColor +
                '}';
    }
}
```

So for example in this image [image] there are 2 sets of 3 adjacent tiles each and 1 set of 4 adjacent tiles

**Update 2**
This is the code I have now, however i am getting an empty map as a result

```
public void calculate(PowerToken[][] allTokens){
        boolean[][] occupiedRed = new boolean[9][9];
        boolean[][] occupiedWhite = new boolean[9][9];

        boolean[][] countedRed = new boolean[9][9];
        boolean[][] countedWhite = new boolean[9][9];

        int scoreRed;
        int scoreWhite;

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
                if (allTokens[i][j].isOnBoard()) {
                    if (allTokens[i][j].getPlayerColor() == Color.RED){
                        occupiedRed[i][j] = true;
                    } else {
                        occupiedWhite[i][j] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        List<List<Point>> clusters = new ArrayList<>();

        int n = occupiedRed.length;
        int[][] label = new int[n][n];
        int last = 1;
        List<int[]> touching = new ArrayList<>();

        //first pass
        for(int i = 1; i<n; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j<n; j++){
                if(occupiedRed[i][j]){
                    //4 way connectivity.
                    int north = 0;
                    int west = 0;
                    int next = 0;
                    if( i-1 > 0 && occupiedRed[i-1][j]){
                        west = label[i-1][j];
                    }
                    if( j-1 < 0 && occupiedRed[i][j-1]){
                        north = label[i][j-1];
                    }
                    if(west != 0){
                        if(north != 0){
                            if(north == west){
                                next = north;
                            } else if(north < west){
                                next = north;
                                touching.add( new int[]{north, west} );
                            } else{
                                next = west;
                                touching.add( new int[]{west, north} );
                            }
                        } else{
                            next = west;
                        }
                    } else if( north != 0 ){
                        next = north;
                    } else{
                        next = last++;
                    }
                } else{
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }


        Map<Integer, Integer> map = touching.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        arr -> arr[0],  // key mapping function
                        arr -> arr[1]   // value mapping function
                ));

        System.out.println(map);
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the `PowerToken` class?

Comment: Yeah, I will modify my post to add it. I have added it

Comment: Yeah I will add a diagram to the question as well

Comment: Yeah a 2x2 square is 4 adjacent squares/tiles

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I haven't come across either of those before

Comment: Here is the theory behind it. I can write it out, though it takes a bit. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling#Graphical_example_of_two-pass_algorithm

Comment: I've not yet worked with algorithms before so I am quite unsure where to begin even with the pseudo-code

Comment: I have updated my answer, it is complete and I believe working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're essentially going to do a connected components algorithm. The input will be with you 9x9 truth table for **one of the colors**.

```
static Map<Integer, List<int[]>> cluster( boolean[][] occupied )
```

This is a [2-pass connect component algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling#Graphical_example_of_two-pass_algorithm). The first pass we go through and make preliminary labels, we also create a "touching" list that keeps track of regions adjacent to each other.

```
    int n = occupied.length;
    int[][] label = new int[n][n];
    int last = 1;
    List<int[]> touching = new ArrayList<>();

    //first pass
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
            if(occupied[i][j]){
                //4 way connectivity.
                int north = 0;
                int west = 0;
                int next = 0;
                if( i > 0 && occupied[i-1][j]){
                    west = label[i-1][j];
                }
                if( j > 0 && occupied[i][j-1]){
                    north = label[i][j-1];
                }
                if(west != 0){
                    if(north != 0){
                        //two labelled regions.
                        if(north == west){
                            //they're the same, it's ok.
                            next = north;
                        } else if(north < west){
                            //label it with the minimum one
                            next = north;
                            touching.add( new int[]{west, north} );
                        } else{
                            next = west;
                            touching.add( new int[]{north, west} );
                        }
                    } else{
                        next = west;
                    }
                } else if( north != 0 ){
                    next = north;
                } else{
                    next = last++;
                }
                label[i][j] = next; //assign the label.
            } else{
                //not occupied.
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

That is the first pass, at the end of the first pass the regions are labelled, but there are touching regions that need to be merged. That can be done with the `touching` list, but it needs to be refined a bit.

This first step merges all of the touching labels in to associated clusters.

```
    List<TreeSet<Integer>> clusters = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for(int[] pair: touching){
        TreeSet<Integer> pair0 = null;
        TreeSet<Integer> pair1 = null;
        for(TreeSet<Integer> cluster: clusters){
            if(cluster.contains(pair[0])){
                pair0 = cluster;
            }
            if(cluster.contains(pair[1])){
                pair1 = cluster;
            }
        }
        if( pair0 == null && pair1 == null){
            //new cluster
            TreeSet<Integer> newCluster = new TreeSet<>();
            newCluster.add(pair[0]);
            newCluster.add(pair[1]);
            clusters.add(newCluster);
        } else if( pair0 == null ){
            pair1.add(pair[0]);
        } else if( pair1 == null ){
            pair0.add(pair[1]);
        } else{
            if(pair0 == pair1) continue;
            //both labels are already in clusters but different clusters.
            pair0.addAll(pair1);
            clusters.remove(pair1);
        }
    }
```

This goes through and creates a mapping, so that all of the values in a cluster will map to the lowest value.

```
    Map<Integer, Integer> fin = new HashMap<>();
    for( TreeSet<Integer> cluster: clusters){
        Integer low = cluster.first();
        for(Integer i: cluster){
            fin.put(i, low);
        }
    }
```

Second pass is just a matter of associating the labels to their keys.

```
    Map<Integer, List<int[]>> result = new HashMap<>();
    //second pass
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
            if( occupied[i][j] ){
                Integer f = fin.computeIfAbsent( label[i][j], k -> k );
                result.computeIfAbsent( f, k -> new ArrayList<>() ).add( new int[]{i, j} );
                label[i][j] = f;
            }
        }
    }
```

Result will contain the label and a collection of int[] that represent all of the points. To use this.

```
Map<Integer, List<int[]>> whiteClusters = cluster(occupiedWhite);
Map<Integer, List<int[]>> redClusters = cluster(occupiedRed);
```

For completeness, here is a compilable working version.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ConnComp{
    static void printArray(int[][] arr){
        for(int[] row: arr){
            for(int i: row){
                System.out.printf("%3d",i);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    
    static void printArray(boolean[][] arr){
        for(boolean[] row: arr){
            for(boolean i: row){
                System.out.print(i ? "  t" : "  f");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    
    static Map<Integer, List<int[]>> cluster( boolean[][] occupied ){
        int n = occupied.length;
        int[][] label = new int[n][n];
        int last = 1;
        List<int[]> touching = new ArrayList<>();

        //first pass
        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
                if(occupied[i][j]){
                    //4 way connectivity.
                    int north = 0;
                    int west = 0;
                    int next = 0;
                    if( i > 0 && occupied[i-1][j]){
                        west = label[i-1][j];
                    }
                    if( j > 0 && occupied[i][j-1]){
                        north = label[i][j-1];
                    }
                    if(west != 0){
                        if(north != 0){
                            //two labelled regions.
                            if(north == west){
                                //they're the same, it's ok.
                                next = north;
                            } else if(north < west){
                                //label it with the minimum one
                                next = north;
                                touching.add( new int[]{west, north} );
                            } else{
                                next = west;
                                touching.add( new int[]{north, west} );
                            }
                        } else{
                            next = west;
                        }
                    } else if( north != 0 ){
                        next = north;
                    } else{
                        next = last++;
                    }
                    label[i][j] = next; //assign the label.
                } else{
                    //not occupied.
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        
        //map reduce
        Comparator<int[]> c = Comparator.comparingInt( arr -> arr[0] );
        Comparator<int[]> c2 = Comparator.comparingInt( arr -> arr[1] );
        c = c.thenComparing(c2);
        
        touching.sort( c );
        List<TreeSet<Integer>> clusters = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for(int[] pair: touching){
            TreeSet<Integer> pair0 = null;
            TreeSet<Integer> pair1 = null;
            for(TreeSet<Integer> cluster: clusters){
                if(cluster.contains(pair[0])){
                    pair0 = cluster;
                }
                if(cluster.contains(pair[1])){
                    pair1 = cluster;
                }
            }
            if( pair0 == null && pair1 == null){
                //new cluster
                TreeSet<Integer> newCluster = new TreeSet<>();
                newCluster.add(pair[0]);
                newCluster.add(pair[1]);
                clusters.add(newCluster);
            } else if( pair0 == null ){
                pair1.add(pair[0]);
            } else if( pair1 == null ){
                pair0.add(pair[1]);
            } else{
                if(pair0 == pair1) continue;
                //both labels are already in clusters but different clusters.
                pair0.addAll(pair1);
                clusters.remove(pair1);
            }
        }
        
        Map<Integer, Integer> fin = new HashMap<>();
        for( TreeSet<Integer> cluster: clusters){
            Integer low = cluster.first();
            for(Integer i: cluster){
                fin.put(i, low);
            }
        }
        
        
        
        System.out.println("occupied");
        printArray(occupied);
        System.out.println("labelled");
        printArray(label);
        
        Map<Integer, List<int[]>> result = new HashMap<>();
        //second pass
        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
                if( occupied[i][j] ){
                    Integer f = fin.computeIfAbsent( label[i][j], k -> k );
                    result.computeIfAbsent( f, k -> new ArrayList<>() ).add( new int[]{i, j} );
                    label[i][j] = f;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("after labelling");
        
        printArray(label);        
        
        return result;
    }
    
    static Random r = new Random(42);
    static boolean[][] getBoard(){
        int n = 9;
        boolean[][] board = new boolean[n][n];
        for(int i = 0; i<50; i++){
            int x = r.nextInt(n);
            int y = r.nextInt(n);
            board[x][y] = true;
        }
        return board;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        cluster(getBoard());
        cluster(getBoard());
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right way to finish it?
```for(int i = 1; i<n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (occupiedRed[i][j]) {
                    label[i][j] = touching.get(i)[j];
                }
            }
        }```
It doesn't seem to be as I am not getting any good results when I print out label

Comment: How would you recommend I properly convert it?

Comment: `Map<Integer, Integer> map = touching.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        arr -> arr[0],  // key mapping function
                        arr -> arr[1]   // value mapping function
                ));`
That seems to be giving me no good values, it's giving me an empty map

Comment: I have updated the original post with the code I have right now that doesn't seem to be generating anything